# How to optimize date range with OR condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one view with two datetime field. 
I want to get a result between two date range matching with any of two datetime fields.

I have write a query for that but i want to optimize that, query is mention as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM viewName 
WHERE country = 'India'
AND ((dateTimeFieldFirst BETWEEN '2016-06-20 16:42:39' 
AND  '2016-06-20 16:52:39') 
OR  (dateTimeFieldSecond BETWEEN '2016-06-20 16:42:39' 
AND  '2016-06-20 16:52:39'))
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: When i am using or condition with SQL server it takes more time to execute i want to use between clause for two fields but with date range it is not possible.

'2016-06-20 16:41:00' BETWEEN  dateTimeFieldFirst AND  dateTimeFieldSecond

with date range

Comment: What is the *nature* of these two datetime columns? Are they meant to be related to each other in some way? And if so, what is your query actually trying to determine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try separating this to two queries using `UNION` :

```
SELECT *
FROM viewName 
WHERE country = 'India'
    AND ((dateTimeFieldFirst BETWEEN '2016-06-20 16:42:39' 
    AND  '2016-06-20 16:52:39') 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM viewName 
WHERE country = 'India'
    AND ((dateTimeFieldSecond BETWEEN '2016-06-20 16:42:39' 
    AND  '2016-06-20 16:52:39')
```

If you know that only one of those columns `(dateTimeFieldFirst ,dateTimeFieldSecond )` can answer the condition, change it to `UNION ALL` which should be faster.

Also, add the proper indexes if they don't exists yet and if its possible(depends if you are calculating the columns in the view or not) :

```
(country,dateTimeFieldFirst)
(country,dateTimeFieldSecond)
```

Comment: Thanks Sagi. time is getting reduce using UNION.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting variables.

```
declare @date1 datetime = '2016-06-20 16:42:39'
declare @date2 datetime =  '2016-06-20 16:52:39'

SELECT *
FROM viewName 
WHERE country = 'India'
AND ((dateTimeFieldFirst BETWEEN  @date1
AND  @date2) 
OR  (dateTimeFieldSecond BETWEEN @date1 
AND  @date2))
```

Don't know how else would you optimise it.

Answer (score 0):

That query is fine and can not be optimized in my opinion.  If you want to get faster query results you will need to look at the table(s) inside the view that contains the date fields.

Start with applying the filter to just that table until you get acceptable results.  Common suggestions would be to make sure the two fields are indexed properly and being used by the query optimizer.

Once you are happy with that performance look at the view itself.  If you need to improve performance there, again you can look at the individual tables being joined together with filters being applied to each of those tables, if any.  If everything performs fine until you put the view together you can optimize the view in a few different ways depending on your exact situation.  Perhaps storing a 'snapshot' of the data in a de-normalized format(maybe a data warehouse) to eliminate joins if you are building a reporting solution.  I also like indexed views when the situation is right.